# Replacing pool light switches with smart switches... is this correct?

Tags: wiring, smart-switch

I'm trying to replace the switches to my two pool lights with smart switches.  The way it is wired now, the neutral wire bypasses both switches and goes directly to the lights.  The smart switches require a neutral, so I need to reconfigure the wiring a bit.  The switches are located in an outside breaker box that has two double pole breakers (one for the pump and one for the Polaris booster pump), and a single pole breaker connected to a GFI outlet.  The pool lights are wired off of that GFI outlet.  This is how I want to wire it so that the neutral goes to each switch.  Does this look right?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both your switches and your GFCI have their line terminals on top and load terminals on the bottom, yes, this is correct.  Double-check that that's the case on your actual devices, because while the way you show it is common, I've seen some that are the opposite as well.

Also, you should pigtail the ground to the GFCI -- it doesn't need to run through it, and you're supposed to wire it in such a way that if you remove one device, nothing else loses ground.

Other than that, everything looks fine.

Comment: Thanks... so you mean connect the ground to the GFI like I have it connnected to the switches?

Comment: @KevinBright, yes, exactly.

Comment: If switches only have a two wire present.And both on the switch ,would be a switch leg.No neutral present.Two whites wire nutted. in box ,neutral is present